# What happens in background or in memory when we cast char * to int *

Tags: c, casting

I am learning type casting of pointers and randomly comes to this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() { 
  char* p="01234567890123456789";
  int *pp = (int *)p;              
  printf("%d",pp[0]);
}
```

On executing above program , output is `858927408`
What are these randome numbers and from where they come ?
What's happening in background or in memory ?

Edit : And if i write `printf("%c",pp[0]);` then output is `0` which is correct but when I change `pp[0]` to `pp[1]` then output is `4` but how ?

Comment: Given `char* p="01234567890123456789";`, `int *pp = (int *)p;` [is a strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and undefined behavior.  It's also undefined behavior if the original `char` address isn't properly aligned for an `int` value. I'd hope the source of that example makes clear that the code is not really proper.

Comment: Yes it is mentioned in example

Comment: "then output is 0 which is correct" Is it? As you cheat your compiler and provide a data type that does not match the format specifier, you invoke undefined behaviour and it is questionable whether the result qualifies as "correct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you express the result in hexadecimal (%x), you can see that:

```
858927408 = 0x33323130
```

- `0x33` is the ascii code for `'3'`
- `0x32` is the ascii code for `'2'`
- `0x31` is the ascii code for `'1'`
- `0x30` is the ascii code for `'0'`

So you just display the memory storing `0123456...` But since your processor is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little), you see the codes inverted.

In memory, you have (in hexa)

```
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38   # 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37   # 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
38 39 00                     # 8 9\0
```

In the `printf("%d...")`, you read the 4 first bytes as a little endian integer, So it display the result of `0x33*0x1000000 + 0x32*0x10000 +0x31*0x100 +0x30`

---

With `%c`, things are different:

If you write `printf("%c", pp[0])`, you will try to print ONE character from `0x33323130`, so `0x30` is retain (in your case, might be an UB in some cases, I'm not sure) so it display "0" which ascii code is `0x30`

If you write `printf("%c", pp[1])`, you will try to print ONE character from `0x37363534`, so `0x34` is retain so it display "4" which ascii code is `0x34`

Comment: I had one more query so , I edited my question can you please reread ?

Comment: I got it now thnx

Answer (score 2):

1. If your C implementation uses ASCII, then the first four bytes of the string `"01234567890123456789"` are 48, 49, 50, and 51 (hexadecimal 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, and 0x33), which are the ASCII codes for the characters “0”, “1”, “2”, and “3”.
2. `(int *)p` converts `p` from `char *` to `int *`. Pointer conversions are not fully defined by the C standard. See the notes below. If there is no alignment problem, in most C implementations, the result of this conversion will point to the same place that `p` points to.
3. Having set `pp` to `(int *)p`, `pp[0]` fetches the bytes at `pp` and interprets them as an `int`. In your implementation, `int` objects have four bytes, and bytes are ordered with the least significant byte in the lowest-addressed memory. So the bytes 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, and 0x33 are read from memory and formed into an integer 0x33323130 (decimal 858927408).

### Notes About Pointer Conversions and Aliasing

Three things about pointer conversions are relevant here:

- If the alignment is incorrect, the pointer conversion is not defined by the C standard. In particular, in many C implementations, `int` objects should be four-byte aligned, whereas `char` objects may have any alignment. If the address in `p` is not correctly aligned for an `int`, then the expression `(int *)p` could cause the program to crash or could cause undesired results.
- Even if the alignment is correct, the C standard does not guarantee what the result of converting a general `char *` to an `int *` is except that converting the result back to `char *` will yield the original pointer (or an equivalent pointer). In many C implementations, this conversion will yield a pointer to the same address, just with a different type.
- The expression `pp[0]` accesses the bytes at `p` as if they were an `int`. This violates a rule in the C standard, called the aliasing rule, that says an object shall have its value accessed only by an expression using a correct type. There are some details about what types are correct, but an `int` is never a correct type for a `char` (or for several `char`). When this rule is violated, the C standard does not define the behavior.

The last point is important because C implementations may or may not support aliasing. Some C implementations support aliasing (meaning they define the behavior even though the C standard does not) because it was widely used, and they want to support existing code that uses it, or because it is needed in certain types of software. Some C implementations do not support aliasing because this allows them to optimize programs better. (If the compiler can assume that an `int *` never points to a `float`, when it may be able to avoid reloading `float` data after assignments through `int` pointers, since those assignments could not have changed the `float` data.) Some compilers have switches so you can enable or disabled aliasing support.

Since aliasing can break your program, you should understand the rules for it, avoid it when not needed, and know how to enable it when needed. In this case, aliasing is not needed to examine the results of reinterpreting the bytes of a string as an `int`. A safe way to do this is to copy the bytes into an `int`, as with:

```
char *p = "01234567890123456789";
int i;
memcpy(&i, p, sizeof i);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of `((51×256+50)×256+49)×256+48`, where 51 is ASCII code of '3' and 50 is ASCII code of '2' and so on. In fact, `pp[0]` points to 4 bytes of memory (int is 4 bytes), and those 4 bytes are "0123", and int on your machine is little-endian, so '0' (which is 48 in numeric) is LSB and '3' is MSB.

`p[1]` is one byte after `p[0]` because `p` is a pointer to byte array, but `pp[1]` is 4 bytes after `pp[0]` because `pp` is a pointer to int array and int is 4 bytes.

Comment: I edited my question can you please reread ? I had one more query.

Comment: I got it now thnx

Answer (score 0):

`858927408` when converted to hex is `0x33323130`

Apperently on your system, you have a *little-endian* format. In this format the LSB of the integer is stored first.

The first 4 bytes of the string are taken for the integer. `"0123"` The ascii values are `0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33` respectively. Since this is little-endian. The LSByte of the integer is `0x30` and the MSbyte of the integer is `0x33`.

That is how you get `0x33323130` as an output.

**Edit** Regarding the additional question from OP

> And if i write printf("%c",pp[0]); then output is 0 which is correct but when I change pp[0] to pp[1] then output is 4 but how ?

When you have `%c` in `printf` and give an integer parameter, you are converting the integer to a character ie, the LS byte is taken `0x30` and this is printed as ASCII.

for `pp[1]` this is the next integer in the array, which is 4 bytes later. So the LS Byte in this case will be `0x34` and `4` is printed after conversion to ASCII.

Comment: I had one more query so , I edited my question can you please reread ?

Comment: I got it now thnx Rishikesh

Answer (score 0):

It just sets the start address of the `int` object at the beginning of the string. The actual value of the `int` will depend on endianess and sizeof(int).

as `"01234567890123456789"` is `{0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39 ...}` in memory if the endianess are little and `sizeof(int) == 4` the value will be `0x0x33323130`. I the endianess are big the value will be `0x30313233`

Comment: Thnx sir I got it now

Comment: DV-ted why? Any explanation